# Can I create a Bitmap that uses malloced buffer I created in native code?

Tags: android, bitmap, native-code

I have a piece of native code where I am mallocing (i.e. allocating) a buffer. I like to draw into this memory using Canvas draw operations.
But Canvas code uses Bitmap as its backing plane. I am wondering if there is a way to wrap native block of memory with Android Bitmap.

Thanks
Videoguy

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a Buffer from JAVA, fill it in Native code and then render it using Canvas. Done, works perfectly.

edited to add an example:

warning, Java bloat ahead

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project
 */
package com.example.hellojni;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.widget.Toast;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.Window;

import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;

import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

public class HelloJni extends Activity
{

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(new Panel(this));
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        myEngineDestroy();
    }

    class Panel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    Bitmap renderbmp = null;
    Paint paint = null;

        public Panel(Context context) {
            super(context);
            getHolder().addCallback(this);
            getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGB_565);
            setFocusable(true);
            setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        }

      @Override 
      public boolean onKeyDown(int i, KeyEvent event) {
      }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

            if ((event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) || 
            (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) )
        {
            if( myEngineMouseInput( (int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY(), 0 ) == 1 )
            drawFrame();
            return true;
            }
        return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        if( renderbmp == null )
        renderbmp = Bitmap.createBitmap( holder.getSurfaceFrame().right-holder.getSurfaceFrame().left, holder.getSurfaceFrame().bottom-holder.getSurfaceFrame().top,Bitmap.Config.RGB_565 );

        if( paint == null )
        paint = new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG);

        myEngineInit( renderbmp, renderbmp.getWidth(), renderbmp.getHeight(), PixelFormat.RGB_565 );

        drawFrame();
        }

    @Override
        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        }

    public void drawFrame() {
            Canvas c;
            c = getHolder().lockCanvas(null);
            c.drawBitmap(renderbmp, 0, 0, paint);
            if (c != null) getHolder().unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
    }

    }

    /* A native method that is implemented by the
     * 'hello-jni' native library, which is packaged
     * with this application.
     */
    public native void myEngineInit( Bitmap bmp, int w, int h, int pf );
    public native int  myEngineMouseInput( int x, int y, int mt );
    public native void myEngineDestroy();

    public native String  unimplementedStringFromJNI();

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("hello-jni");
    }
}
```

and now the NDK side

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2010 The Android Open Source Project
 */

#include <android_native_app_glue.h>

#include <errno.h>
#include <jni.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <android/log.h>
#include <android/bitmap.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define  LOG_TAG    "myapp"
#define  LOGI(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define  LOGW(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_WARN,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)
#define  LOGE(...)  __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR,LOG_TAG,__VA_ARGS__)

/* Set to 1 to enable debug log traces. */
#define DEBUG 0

/* Return current time in milliseconds */
static double now_ms(void)
{
    struct timeval tv;
    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    return tv.tv_sec*1000. + tv.tv_usec/1000.;
}

jobject jbmp = NULL;
ANativeWindow_Buffer draw_buffer = { 0 };

static void cleanup_draw_buffer( JNIEnv* env )
{
    if(jbmp) {
        AndroidBitmap_unlockPixels( env, jbmp);
    }
    draw_buffer.bits = 0;
}

static int init_draw_buffer( JNIEnv* env, jobject jbitmap, int width, int height )
{
    int res = 0, ret;
    LOGI("init_draw_buffer");

    LOGI("window w:%d, h:%d, format: %d", width, height, 4 );

    if( draw_buffer.width != width || 
        draw_buffer.height != height )
    {   
        draw_buffer.width=width;
        draw_buffer.height=height;
        draw_buffer.stride = draw_buffer.width*2;
        res = 1;
    }

    jbmp = NULL;
    if ((ret = AndroidBitmap_lockPixels(env, jbitmap, &draw_buffer.bits)) < 0) {
        LOGE("AndroidBitmap-lockPixels() failed ! error=%d", ret);
    }
    else {
        LOGI("Successfully acquired bitmap pixels: %x", draw_buffer.bits ); 
        jbmp = jbitmap;
    }

    return res;
}

/* simple stats management */
typedef struct {
    double  renderTime;
    double  frameTime;
} FrameStats;

#define  MAX_FRAME_STATS  200
#define  MAX_PERIOD_MS    1500

typedef struct {
    double  firstTime;
    double  lastTime;
    double  frameTime;

    int         firstFrame;
    int         numFrames;
    FrameStats  frames[ MAX_FRAME_STATS ];
} Stats;

static void
stats_init( Stats*  s )
{
    s->lastTime = now_ms();
    s->firstTime = 0.;
    s->firstFrame = 0;
    s->numFrames  = 0;
}

static void
stats_startFrame( Stats*  s )
{
    s->frameTime = now_ms();
}

static void
stats_endFrame( Stats*  s )
{
    double now = now_ms();
    double renderTime = now - s->frameTime;
    double frameTime  = now - s->lastTime;
    int nn;

    if (now - s->firstTime >= MAX_PERIOD_MS) {
        if (s->numFrames > 0) {
            double minRender, maxRender, avgRender;
            double minFrame, maxFrame, avgFrame;
            int count;

            nn = s->firstFrame;
            minRender = maxRender = avgRender = s->frames[nn].renderTime;
            minFrame  = maxFrame  = avgFrame  = s->frames[nn].frameTime;
            for (count = s->numFrames; count > 0; count-- ) {
                nn += 1;
                if (nn >= MAX_FRAME_STATS)
                    nn -= MAX_FRAME_STATS;
                double render = s->frames[nn].renderTime;
                if (render < minRender) minRender = render;
                if (render > maxRender) maxRender = render;
                double frame = s->frames[nn].frameTime;
                if (frame < minFrame) minFrame = frame;
                if (frame > maxFrame) maxFrame = frame;
                avgRender += render;
                avgFrame  += frame;
            }
            avgRender /= s->numFrames;
            avgFrame  /= s->numFrames;

            LOGI("frame/s (avg,min,max) = (%.1f,%.1f,%.1f) "
                 "render time ms (avg,min,max) = (%.1f,%.1f,%.1f)\n",
                 1000./avgFrame, 1000./maxFrame, 1000./minFrame,
                 avgRender, minRender, maxRender);
        }
        s->numFrames  = 0;
        s->firstFrame = 0;
        s->firstTime  = now;
    }

    nn = s->firstFrame + s->numFrames;
    if (nn >= MAX_FRAME_STATS)
        nn -= MAX_FRAME_STATS;

    s->frames[nn].renderTime = renderTime;
    s->frames[nn].frameTime  = frameTime;

    if (s->numFrames < MAX_FRAME_STATS) {
        s->numFrames += 1;
    } else {
        s->firstFrame += 1;
        if (s->firstFrame >= MAX_FRAME_STATS)
            s->firstFrame -= MAX_FRAME_STATS;
    }

    s->lastTime = now;
}

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

struct engine {
    struct android_app* app;

    Stats stats;

    int animating;
};


void
Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_myEngineDestroy( JNIEnv* env,
                                                  jobject thiz )
{
    LOGI("Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_myEngineDestroy");
    cleanup_draw_buffer(env);
}

void
Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_myEngineInit( JNIEnv* env,
jobject thiz, jobject jbitmap, int w, int h, int pf )
{
    LOGI("Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_myEngineInit");    
    init_draw_buffer( env, jbitmap, w, h );
}

jint
Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_myEngineMouseInput( JNIEnv* env,
jobject thiz, int x, int y, int mt )
{
    if( menuvisible )
//    LOGI("Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_myEngineMouseInput, x:%d y:%d mt:%d", x, y, mt);
    return do_the_drawing_stuff(params_ommited); //drawing buffer is unsigned char *dest = draw_buffer.bits;
    else
    return 0;
}
```

So the main rendering part is called a few lines above, and as stated, your buffer is located at draw_buffer structure.

Please examine the passing of a buffer technique and trace its path from the JAVA to C via JNI interface. I took care to make a final bitmap rendering operation without any conversions - fastest approach IMO.

You could ommit that frame counting part, as I took some kind of example as a base and just wanted to lay my hands on that new device I got :)

Comment: @Ulterior..Thanks for detailed example! What I am looking for is a way to set the internal buffer pointer used by Bitmap to a pointer that I came up with (result of mmap()). Bitmap_unlockPixels() gives its pointer which is not useful to me. I still want to render from Java.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is pass the buffer through JNI into the java and create a bitmap from it. see [this page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#copyPixelsFromBuffer%28java.nio.Buffer%29). Then you can use [Canvas.setBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#setBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap%29) to cause it to draw into the buffer.

Comment: Drawing to Canvas is not one time thing. This is being done from a background thread on a timer. I don't plan to malloc the memory, instead memory map an address to my process and use it for rendering. Different process can memory map as well  and access the buffer as my drawing code keeps changing it. I didn't quite understand how can pass a buffer pointer from JNI to Java where it can be used by a Bitmap object.

Answer (score 0):

Bitmaps [use native memory](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=graphics/java/android/graphics/Bitmap.java#l72) by default.