# Is it possible to force an Android Bitmap to have a given memory alignment and stride for its pixels?

Tags: android, c, bitmap, android-ndk, memory-alignment

I have some graphic routines for Android written in C which can manipulate bitmaps and also arrays of pixels (ARGB format, 32bpp). These routines are called from the Java side.

For efficiency, I need each row of the arrays to be 16-byte memory aligned.

But when I manipulate bitmaps, the array I get with lockpixels() is usually 8-byte aligned.

**Is there any way, in Android, to force a Bitmap pixels array to have a given alignment and stride?**

I have read, that creating a bitmap from an allocated array of pixels sometimes does not copy them but just uses the same array, this would be perfect for me. But, if this was the case in Android, don't know if it is always safe nor how to do it.

**EDIT**

After reading more about it and thanks to the coments of Seva Alekseyev, I suppose I must reformulate things. If I understood correctly,

- When a bitmap is created on the Java side, the system chooses the
  memory for its pixels and the stride according to the pixel format,
  so that rows have a minimum alignment.
- But, when ops are performed on a bitmap, the routines still use the stride
  values (whatever they are) to get access to the pixels.
- So, my question would be if it is possible to force the pixel
  structure of a bitmap to be one previously allocated through the JNI,
  with a custom stride (which still allows for the minimum required
  alignment, and perhaps more).
- And this is similar to [Can I create a Bitmap that uses malloced buffer I created in native code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6631412/can-i-create-a-bitmap-that-uses-malloced-buffer-i-created-in-native-code) from @VideoGuy which didn't have any accepted answer, so at the end this may be a   kind of duplicate of a previous question.

But still don't know if it is possible...

Comment: Most likely not. Android's ARGB format does not allow for padding.

Comment: Not sure to understand. So you mean that stride values are used to align rows to a 4 bytes boundary?

Comment: ARGB8888 is 4 bytes; if the whole memory block is aligned to 4 bytes, every row is aligned. There are no bytes but pixels.

Comment: I understand this, but I was refering to the stride value, which can sometimes be larger than width, and if first row is N-byte aligned (which I don't know how to do) can allow all the rows to maintain this alignment. What I don't know is if this value can be forced or the same system decides it. Will do some tests